# Analog of Taylor's formula for formal power series?

Tags: power-series

I'm aware of [Taylor's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) for polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$. More generally though, if working with formal power series over a coefficient ring which contains $\mathbb{Q}$, why does Taylor's formula still hold?

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the Taylor's formula you are alluding to in the context of formal power series?

Comment: I’m guessing that you mean [Newton’s series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton_series), $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Delta^k[f](a)}{k!}(x-a)^{\underline k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{x-a}k\Delta^k[f](a)\;.$$ In what sense do you mean *holds*? You might find the discussion in Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*, pp. 189-192, helpful.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I mean holds as in, "is it true"? This is just the "formal derivative" and I'll always take $a=0$ as I'm interested in ordinary generating functions (with just $x^n$'s). The equality you posted makes sense in this context, but is it true?

Answer (score 3):

A certain formal Taylor's theorem comes up fairly often in the theory of [Vertex Algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_operator_algebra). Haisheng Li and James Lepowsky's [introduction to vertex algebras](http://books.google.com/books?id=dlxCFmV1dKIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=li+lepowsky&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LugQT_XKNuTy0gGBwuGUAw&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=li%20lepowsky&f=false) spends a whole chapter on "formal calculus" proving (among many other things) a formal Taylor's theorem.

There is a more general formal Taylor theorem (taking into account formal logarithms) in [HLZ](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4196) (part II in a series of papers on logarithmic intertwining operators). A student of James Lepowsky named [Thomas Robinson](http://arxiv.org/find/math/1/au%3a+Robinson_T/0/1/0/all/0/1) has written a bunch of papers refining various techniques of formal calculus. In particular [this paper of Robinson](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4891) has a fairly general Taylor theorem appearing as Theorem 4.1.